# wso2 revoke api is not revoking the token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

### WSO2 version: WSO2IS-5.7.0

I am doing proof of concept on WSO2 identity server and my goal is to achieve single sign on for the applications. 
I generated the JWT token from WSO2 using OAUTH2 token API.
I used the revoke API to revoke the token and i got 200 response.
Again i invoked introspect token API and i got response as `active:true` but i suppose to get `active:false`.

Comment: " I generated the JWT token from WSO2 using OAUTH2 token API." what do you mean by JWT ? self contained JWT access token or id_token ?

Comment: During service provider creation, I have enabled option "JWT"

Comment: Can you share more details? For example are you trying this on a single node or a cluster. Requests you send and response you get?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0. It has been reported [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/2255) and will be fixed in 5.8.0 GA release.

Answer (score 0):

i am using wso2 apim version 4.0.0 and identity server as key manager version 5.11.0 when i generate a token from identity server using /oauth2/token api and then revoke that token using /oauth2/revoke the token immediately get expired but in a case if we create token and use it in any api that published from apim and then try to revoke the token using that revoke token api again using identity or apim ip it does not get revoked it still working how to make it possible?
#wso2#wso2 idenity server